Prove this property of three concurrent cevians in a triangle

In triangle $ABC$ and its cevians $AA_1$, $BB_1$, and $CC_1$ all intersecting at the point $D$. Line $C_1A_1$ intersects a line through point $C$ parallel to $AB$ at point $C_2$, and $C_1B_1$ intersects the same line at point $B_2$ as shown. Prove that $CB_2 = CC_2$.
The proof of which I know is the following:

Consider triangles $_\Delta AB_1C_1$ and $_\Delta CB_1B_2$. These triangles are similar by AA similarity because $\angle AB_1C_1 = \angle CB_1B_2$ (vertical angles are congruent) and $\angle B_1AC_1 = \angle B_1CB_2$ (parallelism implies equal alternate angles).
Therefore, their sides are proportional, in particular $\frac{CB_2}{AC_1}=\frac{CB_1}{B_1A}$. Therefore, $CB_2=AC_1\cdot \frac{CB_1}{B_1A}$.
Applying the same reasoning to triangles $_\Delta BA_1C_1$ and $_\Delta CA_1C_2$, we get $CC_2=BC_1\cdot \dfrac{CA_1}{A_1B}$.
Thus the ratio of these sides is the following:
$$
\frac{CB_2}{CC_2} = \frac{AC_1\cdot \frac{CB_1}{B_1A}}{BC_1\cdot \dfrac{CA_1}{A_1B}} = \frac{AC_1\cdot CB_1\cdot A_1B}{BC_1\cdot CA_1\cdot B_1A} = \frac{AC_1}{C_1B}\cdot\frac{BA_1}{A_1C}\cdot\frac{CB_1}{B_1A} = 1.
$$
(The last product of ratios is equal to $1$ by Ceva's theorem on given cevians.)
Therefore, $CB_2=CC_2$, which was to be proven.

I would like to find out the proof, or a proof of whether it is possible to prove, this theorem independently of Thales and areas, through triangle congruence perhaps or some sort of auxiliary construction.
Theorems like ones of Ceva and Menelaus are dependent on the basic proportionality theorem, but it's dependent on areas, so it won't do.
Thoughts:

Perhaps exploring the circle with center at $C$ could help?


You have to elaborate much more on what you mean by "independently of Thales and areas", esp since not many people chase down which theorems are dependent on which facts. EG If Ceva's could be proven using projections on a line, instead of area, is that allowed?

@CalvinLin Oh, yes it is! I would love a proof involving a perpendicular-slope-projection approach.

Since this is very easily coordinate-geometry-able, we can prove it independently of Thales and area (just intersections of lines). I'm too lazy to want to work it out though. $\quad$ BTW Nice generalization of that median observation in the previous question.

@CalvinLin Thanks, I also enjoy the generalization. I have an idea to construct a line parallel to $C_1B_2$ through point $C_2$, and a line parallel to the line $C_1C_2$ through point $B_2$. Let these lines intersect at point $E$. Then $B_2EC_2C_1$ is a parallelogram by definition, and the last thing to prove would be that $E$ lies on $C_1C$, from where the result follows. Or we can construct a segment $CE$ on $CC_1$ and try proving that $B_2EC_2C_1$ is a parallelogram.

The following is a proof of the claimed property that lives in the world of projective geometry (in the plane), and uses the properties of the cross ratio. The notations are slightly changed, the point $C_2$ from OP is now $A_2$, the intersection of $C_1A_1$ with the parallel through $C$ to $AB$. Let $\infty=\infty_{AB}$ be the point at infinity on $AB$ and on all the lines parallel to $AB$. Two further points are introduced, $E=CC_1\cap A_1B_1$ and $K_1=AC_1B\cap A_1B_1$. So we have the following configuration of points and lines in the projective plane:

The relation $B_2C\overset !=CA_2$ is equivalent to
$$
(C,\infty;B_2,A_2)\overset !=-1\ ,
$$
where the expression $(C,\infty;B_2,A_2)$ is the cross ratio of the mentioned four points, explicitly it is $\displaystyle (C,\infty;B_2,A_2)=\frac{CB_2}{CA_2}:\underbrace{\frac{\infty B_2}{\infty A_2}}_{=1}$ and note that the first proportion/fraction involves signed quantities (that do not depend on the chosen orientation on the line $B_2A_2$, each one of the two possible choices leads to the same result).
The exclamation mark over the equality sign means "still to be shown".
Projecting from $C_1$ from the line $B_2CA_2\infty$ to the line $B_1EA_1K_1$, (in the sense of the figure from the wiki link above,) the relation to be shown is equivalent to:
$$
(E, K_1;B_1,A_1)\overset !=-1\ .
$$
Now projecting from this last line to the line $AB$, using first $C$, then $D$ we have:
$$
(C_1, K_1;A,B)
=
(E, K_1;B_1,A_1)
=
(C_1, K_1;B,A)\ .
$$
But the cross ratios at the extremities are by definition inverse to each other, so their common value is $\pm1$. The value $+1$ is excluded, else going back we have $(C,\infty;B_2,A_2)=1$, i.e. $CB_2=CA_2$ as signed lengths, so $A_2=B_2$, and we are in a degenerated situation (that may be excluded from the start). It remains the value $-1$, exactly the value we need.
$\square$

A very nice proof with a very nice idea behind it! Definitely goes into my collection of proofs :) Upvoted; let me see whether i'm able to decently finish my idea of a proof
